# How do I manually install meteor?

Tags: meteor, failed-installation

The automatic installer script from meteor `meteor.sh` stops due to internet connectivity. I looked into the installer script, commented out the lines that try to download the TARBALL. Here is what I did:

I copied the TARBALL_URL from the script:
`https://meteorinstall-4168.kxcdn.com/packages-bootstrap/${RELEASE}/meteor-bootstrap-${PLATFORM}.tar.gz`, replaced

`${RELEASE}` by `1.3.2.4`,

`${PLATFORM}` by `os.osx.x86_64`,

pasted the link in my browser and downloaded a `.tar.gz` file.

After downloading the TARBALL, I commented out the following lines:

```
# rm -rf "$INSTALL_TMPDIR"
# mkdir "$INSTALL_TMPDIR"
# curl --progress-bar --fail "$TARBALL_URL" | tar -xzf - -C "$INSTALL_TMPDIR" -o
```

When I try to run the extracting command `tar -xzf...` it does nothing. Even when I try to extract using GUI, it gives nothing. It's not like the package is corrupted; there is no error message.

**EDIT**

commented out a few more lines:

```
# If you already have a tropohouse/warehouse, we do a clean install here:
# if [ -e "$HOME/.meteor" ]; then
  # echo "Removing your existing Meteor installation."
  # rm -rf "$HOME/.meteor"
# fi

TARBALL_URL="https://meteorinstall-4168.kxcdn.com/packages-bootstrap/${RELEASE}/meteor-bootstrap-${PLATFORM}.tar.gz"

# INSTALL_TMPDIR="$HOME/.meteor-install-tmp"
# rm -rf "$INSTALL_TMPDIR"
# mkdir "$INSTALL_TMPDIR"
# echo "Downloading Meteor distribution"
# curl --progress-bar --fail "$TARBALL_URL" | tar -xzf - -C "$INSTALL_TMPDIR" -o
# rm -rf "${INSTALL_TMPDIR}"
# just double-checking :)
# bomb out if it didn't work, eg no net
# test -x "${INSTALL_TMPDIR}/.meteor/meteor"
# mv "${INSTALL_TMPDIR}/.meteor" "$HOME"
```

Comment: I had a similar issue once, so I downloaded the tar using another device, copied it  and went on from there.

Comment: Did you check [slow start (for developers)](https://github.com/meteor/meteor#slow-start-for-developers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. The extraction command actually extracts the folder to the `$INSTALL_TMPDIR` which is `~/.meteor-install-tmp` but the files are hidden (dot preceded files such as `.meteor/`).

I commented out a few more lines and executed them manually.

- Moved the `.meteor` folder to `$HOME`
- Executed the script